# How do I mark a weapon as a favorite so it's available in the quick access menu?

Tags: fallout-4

I've somehow managed to mark a weapon as a favorite, this draws a little heart next to it:

[image: favorite weapon]

I don't remember doing anything to enable this state (and I've had this gun pretty much from the start of the game with a variety of upgrades performed). However, if I press the <kbd>F</kbd> key on my keyboard, I get a little popup which acts as a quick access to change my currently equipped weapon, and that is quite useful:

[image: quick access pop up]

As you can see, this is empty except my pistol.

How do I mark a weapon as a favorite so it's available in the quick access menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go into the inventory in your Pip-boy, press <kbd>Q</kbd> and then the number of the slot. You can then also access the weapons directly using the number keys.

Comment: On consoles, you go to your inventory, press a button (think it's the right bumper), and the quick access cross pops up. You then select the slot for the item using the D-Pad, as you would when bringing up the quick-access cross during normal play.